# How extract parameters type array from the array of functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

For a simple functions list (function length <= 1, i.e. 1 argument or no arguments at all), like a:

```
const fns = [() => 'a', (b: string) => b, (c: number) => c, (d: boolean) => d];
```

how, as a first approximation, construct generic type ExtractNonEmptyParameters that will be like:

```
type ExtractNonEmptyParameters = ...; // [string, number, boolean]
```

without of `never` or `undefined` params?

In common case wants to get generic type as for example below

```
const fns = [() => 'a', (b: string) => b, (c: number) => c, () => false, (d: boolean) => boolean];

type SimpleFunction = () => any | (a: any) => any;
type ExtractNonEmptyParameters<T extends SimpleFunction[]> = ...; // [string, number, boolean]
```

Comment: What should happen if a function has several arguments?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w6GLvN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing? Note: even with functions with multiple parameters, it will take only the first one, however, I can adapt it to multiple args as well if you provide expected behaviour

Comment: How should 1-arity functions be handled which have an optional parameter or explicit `undefined` or a union which includes `undefined`?

Comment: > What should happen if a function has several arguments

No several, as described at the topic: one or no arguments
> For a simple functions list (function length <= 1, i.e. 1 argument or no arguments at all)

Comment: > How should 1-arity functions be handled which have an optional parameter or explicit undefined or a union which includes undefined?

Wanna without union, no any undefined in result type